# JQuery UI Autocomplete sometimes doesn't show all the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI for autocompletion where I take input and ping a server with that input and end create an array to be given to the source of autocomplete. Right now it works perfect sometimes, but when i print the people array **sometimes** not all the source data shows up on the screen that is shown in console.

```
let input =$("<input type='text'/>")
  .appendTo('#dynamic-form-elements'); 
  input.autocomplete({
     source: [] // Initially empty
  }).on('input', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://lookmeup/json/person/" + input.val(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (parsed_json) {
            let people = [];
            let results = parsed_json.data;
            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                people.push(results[i][1])
            }
            console.log(people)
            input.autocomplete('option', 'source', people);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: do you have any conditions set on your server where it will only show value if the input value met a criteria?

Comment: nope, i can see the correct data is returned, but it is just not showing in the ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this, use source as function: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

```
input.autocomplete({
    source: function(req, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://lookmeup/json/person/" + req.term,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (parsed_json) {
               // do the stuff here and call response callback
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Is this going to trigger the ajax call for each keystroke?

Comment: It's easy to cache the returned data. See this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Comment: Right, the problem is that each keystroke returns a different set of data with a max of 5 entries.

Comment: You mean this request (https://lookmeup/json/person/) will return 5 entries for each call?

Comment: yes so /lookmeup/json/person/**m** will return: ["mike", "matt", "morton", "mango", "megan"] then /lookmeup/json/person/**me** will return: ["merlin", "meghan", "megan", "mek", "mekel"]

Comment: so do you want to combine them?

Comment: Nah, just use the new results everytime

Comment: So you should go with my solution. Everytime user key in something, it will goes to server and takes 5 items.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try that out now and give you the accept if it works =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the "minLength:" attribute in the autocomplete so it waits til you hit the minimum length before it performs the ajax.

You can see this in use here:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

The final code should look like this:

```
input.autocomplete({
    source: function(req, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://lookmeup/json/person/" + req.term,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (parsed_json) {
               // do the stuff here and call response callback
            }
        });
    },
    minlength: 3
})
```

Comment: To answer this question Michael:
"Is this going to trigger the ajax call for each keystroke?"